# How to set cooldown to Tkinter button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am making a voting system which has 4 frames/pages for which I use a class to sift through. The buttons control where to go next.

There is an outro page which is supposed to have a cooldown of 30 seconds; this button is supposed to send the user to the start page once it is re-enabled.

The problem is, the button is only given a cooldown for the first time it is run and the rest of the times it is enabled.
This button is stored within a class, so is there any method I can perhaps reinitialize the class each time the outro frame is brought up?

This is the code:

```
class outropage(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        self.parent = parent

        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.intro_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(
            'outro.jpg').resize((1024, 705), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.intro_img_label = Label(self, image=self.intro_img)
        self.intro_img_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        show_startpage = ttk.Button(self, text='Retrurn to start page',
                                    command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(intropage), state='disabled')
        show_startpage.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        show_startpage.after((1000 * 30), lambda: show_startpage.config(state='enabled'))
```

Code for changing frames:

```
class VotingSystem(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.state('zoom')
        self.geometry('1020x700')
        self.wm_title('Student Council Elections 2017-18')

        icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(
            'logo.ico'))
        self.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, icon)

        # Program can now only be exited through task manager.
        # self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.__callback)

        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (intropage, Headboy, Headgirl, D_Headboy, D_Headgirl, outropage):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(intropage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    @staticmethod
    def __callback():
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you originally attach a `callback` function to your button `button` as command:

```
button = tk.Button(root, command=callback)
```

You can modify the `callback` function, so as to have it disable the button on press, and re-enable it later with the `after` method:

```
def callback():
    original_operations()
    button.config(state='disabled')
    button.after(3000, lambda: button.config(state='active'))
```

Now, redefine `button` with the new callback, just as you did in the first place:

```
button = tk.Button(root, command=callback)
```

---

The following example displays a window with a single button, which prints `'voted'` when pressed, then gets disabled for one second, and gets enabled back.

```
def callback():
    print("voted")
    button.config(state='disabled')
    button.after(1000, lambda: button.config(state='active'))


root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Vote", command=callback)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```